# MacOS multithread issue?

Tags: java, multithreading, eclipse, macos

I am writing a program in java on eclipse that deals with finding the decrypt key of a message with AES algorithm consisting of 16 digits formed by a number ranging from 0 to MAX_VALUE and the remaining digits are all 0. Later I propose the code.

```
private String name;
private int in;
private int end;
private final String FORMAT = String.format("%%0%dd", 16);
private final String KEYWORD = "come";

public Soldier(String name, int in, int end) {
    super(name);
    this.name = name;
    this.in = in;
    this.end = end;
}

private boolean found(File f) {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f)));
        String line = null;
        line = br.readLine();
        while(line!=null) {
            if(line.contains(KEYWORD)) {
                br.close();
                return true;
            }
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        br.close();
        return false;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

public void run() {
    File encryptedFile = new File("document.encrypted");
    File decryptedFile = new File(nome+".decrypted");
    for(int i=in;i<end;i++) {
        if(this.isInterrupted())
            break;
        String key = String.format(FORMAT, i);
        try {
            CryptoUtils.decrypt(key, encryptedFile, decryptedFile);
            try {
                if(found(decryptedFile)) {
                    System.out.println("Key found: "+ key + " Thread: "+name);
                    this.interrupt();
                    break;
                }
            } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Tested key: "+ key + "Thread n: "+ name);
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

this is the class that contains the run method.

```
private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
private static final String TRANSFORMATION = "AES";

public static void encrypt(String key, File inputFile, File outputFile) throws CryptoException {
    doCrypto(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, inputFile, outputFile);
}

public static void decrypt(String key, File inputFile, File outputFile) throws CryptoException {
    doCrypto(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, inputFile, outputFile);
}

private static void doCrypto(int cipherMode, String key, File inputFile, File outputFile) throws CryptoException {
    try {
        Key secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), ALGORITHM);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
        cipher.init(cipherMode, secretKey);
        try (CipherOutputStream out = new CipherOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile)), cipher)) {
            Files.copy(inputFile.toPath(), out);
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        throw new CryptoException("Error encrypting/decrypting file", ex);
    }
}
```

This is the decrypt class.

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2850972529362612601L;

public CryptoException(String message, Throwable throwable) {
    super(message, throwable);
}
```

This is the exception that is raised when there is an error in the decryption. This exception is however managed by printing on the screen the key number tested as seen in the run method. I then show the stack trace of the error.

```
decrittazione.CryptoException: Error encrypting/decrypting file
    at decrittazione.CryptoUtils.doCrypto(CryptoUtils.java:42)
    at decrittazione.CryptoUtils.decrypt(CryptoUtils.java:23)
    at decrittazione.Soldier.run(Soldato.java:50)
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.unpad(CipherCore.java:975)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1056)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:853)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2208)
    at decrittazione.CryptoUtils.doCrypto(CryptoUtils.java:36)
    ... 2 more
```

```
    Soldier s1 = new Soldier("1", 0, /*endNumber*/);
    Soldier s2 = new Soldier("2", /*inNumber*/, /*endNumber*/);
    Soldier s3 = new Soldier("3", /*inNumber*/, /*endNumber*/);
    Soldier s4 = new Soldier("4", /*inNumber*/, /*endNumber*/);
    Soldier s5 = new Soldier("5", /*inNumber*/, /*endNumber*/);
    Soldier s6 = new Soldier("6", /*inNumber*/, /*endNumber*/);
    Soldier s7 = new Soldier("7", /*inNumber*/, /*endNumber*/);
    Soldier s8 = new Soldier("8", /*inNumber*/, /*endNumber*/);
    Soldier s9 = new Soldier("9", /*inNumber*/, /*endNumber*/);
    Soldier s10 = new Soldier("10", /*inNumber*/, /*endNumber*/);
    Soldier s11 = new Soldier("11", /*inNumber*/, /*endNumber*/);
    Soldier s12 = new Soldier("12", /*inNumber*/, /*endNumber*/);
    Soldier s13 = new Soldier("13", /*inNumber*/, /*endNumber*/);
    Soldier s14 = new Soldier("14", /*inNumber*/, /*endNumber*/);
    Soldier s15 = new Soldier("15", /*inNumber*/, 2147483647);

    s1.start();
    s2.start();
    s3.start();
    s4.start();
    s5.start();
    s6.start();
    s7.start();
    s8.start();
    s9.start();
    s10.start();
    s11.start();
    s12.start();
    s13.start();
    s14.start();
    s15.start();

    while(true) {
        if(s1.isInterrupted() || s2.isInterrupted() || s3.isInterrupted() || s4.isInterrupted() || s5.isInterrupted() || s6.isInterrupted() || s7.isInterrupted() || s8.isInterrupted() || s9.isInterrupted() || s10.isInterrupted() || s11.isInterrupted() || s12.isInterrupted() || s13.isInterrupted() || s14.isInterrupted() || s15.isInterrupted()) {
            s1.interrupt();
            s2.interrupt();
            s3.interrupt();
            s4.interrupt();
            s5.interrupt();
            s6.interrupt();
            s7.interrupt();
            s8.interrupt();
            s9.interrupt();
            s10.interrupt();
            s11.interrupt();
            s12.interrupt();
            s13.interrupt();
            s14.interrupt();
            s15.interrupt();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally this is the main method.

This code performing tests with a key chosen by me and a message chosen by me on windows works without problems. By switching to MacOS always on Eclipse (same version, same JDK etc.) instead when it is time to test the key the program cannot decrypt the message and continue with the subsequent keys until no they are exhausted and therefore not the desired result.

If I have not been able to explain myself well I apologize but I would not know how else to explain the matter. I apologize even if it is not the best code in the world but I am a beginner.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the SO club. Try to update your question and make it a bit more clear. Also please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)! Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing here anybody can use to help, and saying there are "problems" isn't diagnostic--it's like telling your auto mechanic your car doesn't work and asking her to fix it remotely.

Comment: Java threads work fine on macOS - Eclipse itself uses many threads.

Comment: Thanks for the directives you gave me. I modified the post by putting the code and trying to better explain the situation.

Comment: `inputStream.read(inputBytes);` is not guaranteed to fill the inputBytes array.  That’s why the method returns a count telling you how many bytes were actually read.

Comment: That aside, you can use [Files.readAllBytes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes%28java.nio.file.Path%29), or you can use [Files.copy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,java.io.OutputStream%29) with a [CipherOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.html) instead of reading all the bytes yourself.

Comment: If you’re using Java 9 or later, then yes, that will work.  Of course, if your files are very large, reading all the bytes into memory may create performance problems.  CipherOutputStream would solve that.

Comment: @VGR Forgive my ignorance but would you suggest me how to implement it?

Comment: When you say “the program cannot decrypt the message” what do you mean?  How do you know it’s failing?

Comment: @VGR I'll explain right away.  I created another class called Test which takes a text file from the disk and encrypts it with a 16-digit key with AES.  Now if the program that tests the keys works, print on the screen that has found the key, the program stops and going to the destination file you will find the decrypted message.  When it does not work when testing the key, the program does not indicate that the file has been decrypted, on the contrary, it raises an exception as if the key were incorrect and continues to test other keys.  As a result, the program doesn’t stop.

Comment: That exception is very important information.  Please include that exception’s full stack trace, including all ‘Caused by:’ sections, in your question.

Comment: @VGR I've updated the code with the Exception and the full stack trace

Comment: If you make use of CipherOutputStream, and remove all of the code following that `try` block, do you still get the exception?

Comment: @VGR Thanks a lot it finally works !!! I did 10 tests and it worked in 100% of cases. One last thing if I don't bother. To see the progression of the keys and maybe see them printed on the screen, I enter the code directly after the try block or in the run method?

Comment: Certainly.  Printing and logging statements should be safe to add, regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t know for sure what is causing your problem, but I know that `inputStream.read(inputBytes);` is not guaranteed to fill the inputBytes array.  That’s why the method returns a count telling you how many bytes were actually read.

You would be better off using `inputBytes = inputStream.readAllBytes();` if you are using Java 9 or later.

If any of the files are large, reading the entire contents into memory is going to hurt performance.  A file larger than 2 gigbytes won’t fit into a byte array at all.

A solution to this is to use a [CipherOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.html):

```
Key secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), ALGORITHM);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
cipher.init(cipherMode, secretKey);

try (CipherOutputStream out = new CipherOutputStream(
    new BufferedOutputStream(
        new FileOutputStream(outputFile)), cipher)) {

    Files.copy(inputFile.toPath(), out);
}
```

Comment: Meanwhile, thanks for the reply, but unfortunately carrying out tests, the algorithm has a 60% success. Better than before but still not perfect. I've updated the CryptoUtils class on top. Maybe I made a mistake.